# error: cannot find symbol IOUtils.copy(in, out);

Tags: java

Using Apache ANT to built. Included the commons-io-2.4.jar in classpath.
Compiler shows this error:

```
 error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         IOUtils.copy(in, out);
```

### EDIT - code

```
File f1 = new File("c:\\json\\user.json");
 File f2 = new File("c:\\json\\user1.json");

 InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);
 OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2, true); // appending output stream

 try {
    IOUtils.copy(in, out);
 }
 finally {
     IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
     IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
 }
```

### EDIT- Answer

Did a mistake with the imports.
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

Comment: Can you share build file and relevant code snippets.

Comment: Do you have an import statement for IOUtils (I know it is basic, but you never know ...)?

Comment: import org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils; is this ok?

Comment: i think its with the import statement.

Comment: `i think` you are not even sure! please share your full code.

Comment: @Edmon I could accept yr answer, you were correct about the mistake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To try few things please:

- Verify that code has:

  `import org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils;`
- Verify that build.xml has a classpath reference for javac task that contains:

  `<classpath>

      <pathelement path="${classpath}"/>

      <pathelement location="lib/commons-io-2.4.jar"/>

  </classpath>`